# Is there a proper name for a function that maps and filters?

Tags: computer-science

If I have a higher-order function that takes a sequence of elements and an input function that maps and filters elements, is there a proper name for that? Processing the elements of the sequence could be done in parallel, so the input function cannot rely on state between elements. Thus the name of the higher order function is not a reduce or a fold.

In Haskell it is called mapMaybe, but that name is too tied to the Maybe type.

EDIT:
Just to clarify - I am not asking anything about Haskell or any other specific programming language. I am asking about nomenclature that stretches across programming languages.

Comment: It's a "*Transform*".

Comment: @RBarryYoung Do you have a reference? In most languages/libraries I think a transform just means a map.

Answer (score 0):

why do you say it is not a fold?

foldr f [] xs can do "map and filter":

```
f p n = if p < 0 then n
        else (sqrt p):n
```

filters out negative numbers and maps the rest to sqrt of the numbers.

Comment: I say it is not a fold, because a fold is too general. It can keep state between elements, so it cannot be performed in parallel.

Comment: @Gurgeh Parallellism of execution does not depend on fold; it only depends on the function. For example, if the function is monoidal multiplication, then it is parallellisable. Oh, and btw, map f = foldr ((:) . f) []. (:) is the monoidal multiplication here (being a particular case of (++)).

Comment: A fold can do all sorts of things, for example express mappings. That does not mean that a mapping should be called a fold. A mapping is a specialization of a fold. Just like a fold is a specialization a function. I am interested in the name of a higher-order function that can map and filter but _not_ a general fold. Like mapMaybe.

Comment: @Gurgeh then it must be mapMaybe. There must be a way to signal to the higher order function whether you mapped the value, or filtered it out. Type Maybe adds this extra point to any type. So the function you pass to it will necessarily will be a->Maybe b

Comment: Why are you thinking in Haskell? I am asking for what a higher-order function (that works exactly like mapMaybe in Haskell) should be called in general. MapMaybe is obviously not a good name since it is tied to Haskells Maybe type, which is not how other programming languages would implement it. Does computer science (see tag) have a general name designating such a function?

Comment: Yes, haskell has nothing to do with this. The question must be "what's the name of the dependent type \X->1+X".

Comment: That is not my question.